# Adding the same strings together (MATLAB)

Tags: string, matlab, ascii, matlab-figure

So I'm trying to sum up two or more strings together; Lets say: Calculate the number of times the bread is eaten by each pet: 'Dog', 'Cat', 'Bunny'. If the string 'Dog' appear multiple times and I want to add them up, how would I do it? ie. 'Dog' + 'Dog' = 2

Comment: Can you have an equation "Dog" + "Dog" + "Cat" + "Bunny" and you'd like the totals 2, 1 and 1 as output? As an example.

Answer (score 1):

This might be an option. With further implementation details, we can adapt the answer to fit your use case more precisely. Here the function `count()` is used to evaluate how many times the string `Dog, Cat and Bunny` appear in the string declared as `Bread_Eaten` which summarizes the eating occurrences. The second implementation involves using  symbolic function that can add the `syms` (symbolic variables) directly. This method will result in the output have `Dog, Cat and Bunny` concatenated at the end of each term such as `2*Dog`.

### Method 1: Counting the Strings using `count()` Function

```
Bread_Eaten = "Dog" + "Dog" + "Cat" + "Bunny";

Amount_Dog_Ate = count(Bread_Eaten,"Dog");
Amount_Cat_Ate = count(Bread_Eaten,"Cat");
Amount_Bunny_Ate = count(Bread_Eaten,"Bunny");

fprintf("The dog ate bread %d time(s)\n",Amount_Dog_Ate);
fprintf("The cat ate bread %d time(s)\n",Amount_Cat_Ate);
fprintf("The bunny ate bread %d time(s)\n",Amount_Bunny_Ate);
```

[image: Output Results 1]

### Method 2: Using a Set of Symbolic Variables

```
syms Dog Cat Bunny;
Bread_Eaten = Dog + Dog + Cat + Bunny + Bunny + Cat;
Bread_Eaten
```

[image: Output Results 2]

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**